# Extracting month from date in dd/mm/yyyy format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I can't get month and day from date in the correct format.

I'm using both `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date1']).month`
and `pd.to_datetime(parity['date1']).dt.month` but it still retrieves day as month and only if value is larger than 12 it considers it as day.
Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably something to do with the datetime format. It seems to be using the American `year-day-month` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify format of dates:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.month
```

Or set parameter `dayfirst=True`:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], dayfirst=True).dt.month
```

Comment: thanks! but in case of date2 it doesn't work. is there way to improve  it for date also?

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev - use `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2']).dt.month `

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work. I tried to create m2 and m3 for date2 but it didn't work.

Comment: @jezarel I added image to post.

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev - try `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], format='%Y:%d:%m').dt.month` if format is `YYYY-DD-MM`

Comment: @jezarel tried as m4. didn't work, added screen to post.

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev - format in `date2` is `YYYY-MM-DD` ? Or `YYYY-DD-MM` ?"

Comment: @jezarel YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev - can you try `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], format='%Y-%d-%m').dt.month` ? If use `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], format='%Y:%d:%m').dt.month` it not geenrate error?

Comment: @jezarel  tried, and added screen to post. Can't understadn what is the problem but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev - really weird. What is `print (df['date2'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezarel  added screen to post.

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev use `df['m5'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'].astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m').dt.month`

Comment: @jezarel returned error both for '%Y-%d-%m' and '%Y:%d:%m'. added screens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244634/discussion-between-jezrael-and-zaur-guliyev).